# How to do HTTP GET within CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Let's say I have a table called **user**

[image]

I want to make a HTTP call roughly like this
http://my.awesome.server/dev_api/index.php/login/get_user.php?user=steven&password=12345

Which checks the database if there's a user 'steve' with the password '12345'. These are my codes.

**controller**

```
<?php
if(!defined("BASEPATH")) exit("No direct script access allowed");

class login extends CI_Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->model("login_model"); 
    $data["users"]=$this->login_model->get_user(); 

    $this->load->view("login_view", $data);
  }
}
```

**model**

```
    class Login_model extends CI_Model {

        function get_user(){
            // get username, like $_GET['user']
            $user = $this->input->get('user');

            // get the password and MD5-ed it, like md5($_GET['password'])
            $md5_pass = md5($this->get('password'));

            // the where condition
            $this->db->where(array('userName' => $user, 'password' => $md5_pass)); 

            // ok, now let's query the db
            $q = $this->db->get('user');

            if($q->num_rows() > 0){

                foreach ($q->result() as $row){
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }

?>
```

**view**

```
<?php

if (!empty($users)){
    foreach ($users as $u){
        echo $u->userId .' '. $u->userName.' '.$u->password.' ';
    }
}

?>
```

Then I opened this on browser:
http://my.awesome.server/dev_api/index.php/login/. The result is
[image]

How to properly make a HTTP call, then?

Comment: Why would you make a HTTP call to the same system? That adds a bunch of needless overhead and will be quite slow. You also need to stop using MD5 for passwords - it's incredibly insecure.

Comment: Dont use md5 for passwords not to be used for passwords these days http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: Also I would not put password in url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to work against the framework you are using.

CodeIgniter abstract working with GET parameters by proposing you to use *URL segments*.

The URI scheme in CodeIgniter is as follow ([see docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)):
`controller/method/params...`

It is divided in **segments**:

1. the controller (mandatory)
2. the method (mandatory, but may be implied in case of `index`, see below)
3. the first param (optional)
4. the second param (optional)
5. ... and so on

You want to use the method `index()` of the controller `Login`, it translates to

> http://my.awesome.server/dev_api/index.php/login/index

Also, with mode_rewrite activated with htaccess, it could be simplified in

> http://my.awesome.server/dev_api/login/index

Now, `index()` is a special method as it is the one called by default in a controller. Hence the final URL would be:

> http://my.awesome.server/dev_api/login

Now, if you want to pass parameters to your function, CodeIgniter does this through subsequent segments.

But you need to declare them in the controller method.

```
class login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index($user = null, $password = null)
    { 
        // Check for $user / $password emptiness

        // ...

        // Use $user / $password as needed
        $data["users"]=$this->login_model->get_user($user , $password); 

        // use the results...
    }
}
```

And now you could call with:

> http://my.awesome.server/dev_api/login/index/steven/12345

Notice that I've put `index` in the URL? It's because when passing parameters, the method is mandatory.

---

That said, I will reiterate what other people have said:

1. Avoid passing login/password through GET. Prefer POST.
2. Use an encrypted connection (**HTTPS**)
3. Do NOT hash your password with md5 or even sha1. You need a strong algorithm. You also need to salt. Anyway, PHP got you covered with [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Don't reinvent the wheel.

Good luck.

Comment: Hmm I see. But the database query is done in the model. How do I pass $user & $password to it?

Comment: Update your `get_user()` function from `login_model` to accept `$user` and `$password` as parameters... See my update.

Answer (score 2):

The method in your model is name as `get_user()` while you call it as `login_model->get()`

More over you should use POST instead of GET for username and password.

Also use [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or another hashing algorithm instead of MD5 it's more secure. 
[DO NOT USE MD5](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)

Answer (score 0):

if you are passing data via url http://my.awesome.server/dev_api/index.php/login/get_user.php?user=steven&password=12345

You can retrieve it via URI segment

```
$user= $this->uri->segment(3); 
$password= $this->uri->segment(4);
```

Sorce: 
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html

It is posible that this line  `$md5_pass = md5($this->get('password'));`  is setting the error if $this->get('password') is empty.